# React.js and rich datagrid components OR at least hack [2015]

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jqgrid, reactjs

Before, we were using [jqGrid](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/).
Later we moved to Backbone.js, started working with [Backgrid](http://backgridjs.com/).

Now, we are evaluating moving **Backbone.Views to React** components and we can't find any grid plugin / add-on fat and rich as those mentioned.

Basically, we need everything you might imagine, selecting, filtering, paging, editing, sorting, subgrids...Out of the box :) I know we can make our own table component, adding sorting and stuff, but that's way too much work for us. We were more hoping for some "reuse" :)

**Is there some grid component I missed on Google?**

or

**Is there some (nasty) way of using some of the old DOM dependant, jquery, backbone.js stuff with React?**

Comment: http://www.reactdatagrid.com/ has selecting, filtering, editing, sorting, subgrids - out of the box, like you asked.

Comment: Thanks. This question is now 2 years old, I can imagine there are a lot of awesome plugins available :)

Comment: React documentation discusses integration with other libraries, especially jquery and Backbone.js : https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html. For datagrid candidates, you can see in my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ReactDataGrid](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/) is a datagrid for React and has a lot of that functionality mentioned, namely sorting, filtering, selecting, custom formatters and editors, copy and paste, cell drag down, frozen columns. Pagination and subgrids are on the road map. Check it out

Comment: How will you add the pagination with fetch? Any such example?

Answer (score 8):

You can use any plain javascript library with React. Even if it changes the DOM directly. One exception is that this library should change only its own piece of DOM.
You can "disable" React for component. React will not work with this component after first render.

```
React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        myNativeJsGrid.init({
            domElem: this.getDOMNode(),
            data: props,
            onRowRemove: function(row){
                this.props.onRowRemove(row);
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    shouldComponentUpdate: function(props) {
        myNativeJsGrid.update({
            domElem: this.getDOMNode(),
            data: props
        });
        return false;
    },
    render: function() {
        return React.DOM.div();
    }
});
```

Note `return false;` in `shouldComponentUpdate`. It indicates to React that it shouldn't update anything in the DOM (we do it manually).

Implementation of `componentDidMount` and `shouldComponentUpdate` depends on grid API. But idea is that you should:

- init grid in `componentDidMount`
- update grid in `shouldComponentUpdate`
- use internal grid events to call functions from `props` to update data if necessary

Answer (score 5):

Start Use: [Griddle](http://dynamictyped.github.io/Griddle/) and its available in NPM as well.

1. Custom Formatting
2. Infinite Scrolling
3. Custom Styling

`npm install griddle-react --save`

Answer (score 3):

Check out http://zippyui.github.io/react-datagrid/#/, it's a nice grid, with a lot of functionality built-in

Comment: Looks like it no longer exists.  Just *poof* -- gone.

Answer (score 1):

There is also http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table
Built completely on Bootstrap tables.